# Can't get HTTP request time with goaccess from nginx log

Tags: webserver, logging, nginx

I've we websites hosted on nginx web server. I've added HTTP request duration to nginx logs, and nginx logs that data.
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html

I also have goaccess log analyzer and it works just fine with one nasty exception. I can't get the HTTP request time parameter although in documentation they say it is possible

> `%D`: The time taken to serve the request, in microseconds.

Here is the url, please help.
http://goaccess.io/man#custom-log

The last number is request duration.

```
192.168.17.1 - - [05/Feb/2015:22:24:29 +0400] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 12015 "http://www.watch-sell.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.94 Safari/537.36" "-" 20.178
```

Log Format in `goaccess.conf`

```
log-format %h %^ %^ [%d:%^] "%r" %s %b "%R" "%^" %T
```

Answer (score 2):

`20.178` is the time in seconds with milliseconds after the dot. [GoAccess](http://goaccess.io) will output 20.18 s. Here's the format to use:

```
%h %^[%d:%^] "%r" %s %b "%R" "%u" %^ %T
```

So running the following should do it:

```
goaccess -M -H -f log --log-format='%h %^[%d:%^] "%r" %s %b "%R" "%u" %^ %T' --date-format='%d/%b/%Y'
```